# How can you import from outside a project in Rascal?

Tags: rascal

Is there a way to import rascal modules from other rascal projects in your eclipse work-space? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like normal eclipse projects, you have to put this dependency in your build path. Internally, Rascal projects are normal java projects with rascal added on top. This is so that you can mix java and rascal code.

Open your project's settings, and open: `Java > Compiler > Building`, and in the  `Projects` tab, add the other project.

**Remember to restart the REPL/Terminal for this to take effect**

Comment: It's a "project reference" which needs to be added. And it will be reflected in the Rascal navigator view as one of the "jars" in the search path.